# sencha app build native without minify JS

Tags: build, sencha-touch, minify

I want be able to build a native app, but without minifying the JS so I can debug it later confortably.

Currently I'm executing:

```
sencha app build native
```

How can I be able to build without minifying JS files?
Thanks

Answer (score 8):

For native build, you can only have testing option after upgrade to Sencha CMD 5.x, refer to

http://docs.sencha.com/cmd/5.x/cmd_upgrade_guide.html

Under Cordova / PhoneGap

"*These build profiles ensure that all of the “sencha app build” command variations are equivalent to previous releases. You will notice, however, that “native” is now a build profile instead of an environment (like “testing” or “production”). This means you can now do “sencha app build native testing” which was previously not possible.*"

So, the command should be

```
sencha app build native testing
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to use this command line instead:

```
sencha app build testing
```

That way, all JavaScript source files are bundled but not minified; and you could debug easily.

See [Sencha CMD 4 documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/cmd/4.0.0/#!/guide/command_app_touch) for more details.